# How to handle In-App Purchases auto renewal subscription for different users in same device in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing **Auto-Renewal Subscription In app Purchase** to remove advertisement. I have a few questions Please clarify. Really appreciate your help.

1. **User1** make purchase a plan to remove ad which is 30 days plan from **device1** with his iTunes account.

[image]

2. **User1** logged out from the application.
3. Now **User2** logged in same application from same device **device1**. And **User2** want to make purchase a plan to remove ad which is 30 days plan. But **User2** can't make the In-app purchase. While **User2** tapped the In-app Purchase button, It shows auto alert that indicates

[image]

4. **User2** can't able to do in-app purchase feature.

How we can make sure that multiple user can access In-App Purchases in same device?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How to you make a purchase? Show some code

Comment: Hello please let me know how you implemented auto-renewal subscription. Because I don't find any method or document which show me the correct code. is there any listener which give me status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That thing is coming because of the **iTunes account** through which user1 has bought that subscription, it still exists for the second user2. That's why it's showing the currently subscribed subscription for that user. So If user2 wants to buy it, he has to sign out from previous user (in this case user1) itunes connect account from the device and has to try.

Comment: I'm glad you found helpful :)

Comment: Correct. That's why most of the time owner shouldn't share his apple id